# URL to open track in SoundCloud iOS app

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I would like to open a SoundCloud track in the SoundCloud iOS app. I was under the impression that the correct url scheme to use is `soundcloud:track:[track_id]`.

This opens the SoundCloud app but doesn't select the correct track.

Can anyone shed some light on how to get this functioning correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tracks should be in plural, like this:

```
soundcloud:tracks:[track_id]
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks. Thought I'd already tried that but obviously not.

Comment: Hey Fred Can you please confirm the URL ? Cause its not working for me. Instead of I have tried. soundcloud://tracks/63085864 but its not selecting any track

Comment: Hi @Tariq-iPHONEProgrammer, yes, it works for me. You can check how I used it in this project: https://github.com/fredr/sounds-like-a-stream

Answer (score 1):

The scheme is correct, but the notation is a little strange. There is a literal colon in it. The following link is of the correct form and currently works on iOS.

```
soundcloud://tracks:125636702
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if/when this changed, but the current URL is soundcloud:sounds:[track_id]