# Open soundcloud in ios

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I'm trying to find the way to open Soundcloud app in iOS from my app like FB, Twitter on some profile. I tried searching, but I only found what the Soundcloud SDK is. I just want to open the profile of an user and didn't find the answer.

In facebook app it work like this: `fb://profile/354194261322518`, Twitter and Instagram have too, but Soundcloud seems not has functional for that.

If open `soundcloud://` it works for opening but how to open profile?

Answer (score 1):

From the API:

`soundcloud:tracks:[track_id]`

Correctly formatted URL:

`soundcloud://tracks/[track_id]`

Example:

`soundcloud://tracks/63085864`

Similar SO thread:

[URL to open track in SoundCloud iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430436/url-to-open-track-in-soundcloud-ios-app)

Playing with the SoundCloud API:

https://github.com/fredr/sounds-like-a-stream